# When I use the Django generic How can I Bring two models

Tags: python, django

I have two models : Advertisment and Banner

when I using "generic view" How can I Bring together at the same time
The code below bring only one Advertisment

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',


    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
        model               = Advertisment,
        context_object_name = 'advertisment',
    ), name='cars-advertisment-detail'),

    url(r'^$', SearchView.as_view(), name='cars-advertisment-search'),
)
```

Comment: read this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576202/how-can-i-pass-two-models-to-a-class-based-generic-view

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `get_context_data()` method of the class based view (as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#adding-extra-context)).

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class YourDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Advertisment
    context_object_name = 'advertisment'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(YourDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'banner_id' in self.kwargs:
            context['banner'] = get_object_or_404(Banner, pk=self.kwargs['banner_id']
        return context
```

I guess you'll need to update your url conf to include a primary key for the Banner model too.

```
from your_app.views import YourDetailView

  url(r'^(?P<ad_pk>\d+)/(?P<banner_pk>\d+)/$', YourDetailView.as_view(), name='cars-advertisment-detail'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Aidan's answer is good if you only want to do it for a single view, but if you want to show banners on each page automatically, you have two main options.

One is to create a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that renders the banner, and add this tag to your templates where you want banners to be shown.

Your tag could look like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('banner.html')
def banner_display():
    random_banner = Banner.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    return {'the_banner': random_banner}
```

Then, you would create a template that shows the banner:

```
<a href="{{ the_banner.url }}"><img src="{{ the_banner.url|safe }}" /></a>
```

In your templates, where you need the banner, you would just say `{% banner_display %}`

The other option you have is to create a custom [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).  This will inject your banner as a normal variable in all requests.  This is perhaps even simpler:

```
def banner_display(request):
    random_banner = Banner.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    return {'the_banner': random_banner}
```

You should save this in a file and then add it to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.  Now in every template you have a variable `{{ the_banner }}`.