# django: How to use generic view with two models

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models called `customer` and `building`. how can I use these two models to view generically in one template using class based generic view.

Here is my *urls.py* to view my customer

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url(r'^customer/', customerView.as_view(), name= "customer_view"),
)
```

Here is my *view.py* for customer

```
class customerView(UpdateView):
    template_name="customer.html"
    model = customer
    form_class = customerForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(customerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        context['pk'] = 1
        context['numberOfObjects'] = customer.objects.all().count()
        return context

    def get_object(self, queryset = None):
        try: 
            obj = customer.objects.get(id = 1)
        except: 
            obj = customer.objects.create(id = 1)
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):

        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("customer_view", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}))
```

Here is some of the code for customer.html to view both `customer` and `building`

```
<form action="" method="post">  
{% csrf_token %}

 {{ form.id }}  
    <div class="text_label"  >FIRST NAME</div>
    <div class="text_input">{{ form.FIRST_NAME }}</div>     
    <div class="text_label" >LAST NAME</div>
    <div class="text_input">{{ form.LAST_NAME }}</div>      

    <div class="text_label" >BUILDING USE</div>
    <div class="text_input3">{{ form.BUILDING_USE }}</div></td>     
    <div class="text_label" >BUILDING FLOORSPACE</div>
    <div class="text_input3">{{ form.BUILDING_FLOORSPACE }}</div></td>      
    <div class="text_label">BUILDING YEAR</div> 
    <div class="text_input3" >{{ form.BUILDING_YEAR }}</div></td></tr>

rest of the code....//the first part is from the class customer and the second part is from the class building.
```

My problem is I can generic view the class customer but not the class building. How do I achieve this...I'm still an amateur in django and still a looong way to go to be good. Please forgive me if I ask a noob question. Have check in this [How can I pass two models to a class based generic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576202/how-can-i-pass-two-models-to-a-class-based-generic-view) but still blank. Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `get_context_data()` you can add your new object.

```
context['building'] = building.objects.get(name="Building name")
```

then you can call it in your template like this

```
{{ building.name }}
```

If you wanna use it in a form, it will prove much tricker to edit two models properly at the same time.

There's [a great SO post explaining why this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276398/multiple-form-classes-in-django-generic-class-views)

Comment: Thanks @limelights for the reply. sorry to ask again do I have to write  (name="Monkey") or??sorry a bit confuse now...

Comment: No, that was just for an example, but you have to filter for something or if you want all buildings you do `building.objects.all()` - i updated my answer

Comment: hi again @limelights. I have add to what you have suggested but I still have the same problem. It will not give me the right output. Do I have to change also in the model = customer and model = building??

Comment: You're trying to access it via the form, right? As I said, that's very tricky in your case. I believe you cannot do it using an `UpdateView`

Comment: yes that is right...@limelights...:( If I cannot use it using Updateview is there any way so that I can maybe change something so that I may be able to achieve the output that I want??Do you have any suggestion? Thanks again..

Comment: Build your own form that has all the fields and then when you save you have to do the custom logic for it. It requires a lot of work and wont be as "clean" but it works.

Comment: thank you @limelights..so meaning that I build one form that have both the customer and building and then when come to save the form then i do the custom logic..am i right??..:)